# Cannot set/get SQL session_context in .NET C#

Tags: c#, sql-server, sessioncontext

I had this working a few months ago but i cant read back a session variable set 
in code but i can in the query analyzer..
this C# code sets the variable

```
String.Format("EXEC sp_set_session_context N'TENANTID', '{0}'", tenantId); 
SPSDatabaseInfo.ExecuteScalar(SPSDatabaseInfo.DBType.MSSQLServer, _connString, sql, null);
```

but when i read it back immediately with

```
sql = "select SESSION_CONTEXT(N'TENANTID') AS SESSION_ID"; 
var retVal = SPSDatabaseInfo.ExecuteScalar(SPSDatabaseInfo.DBType.MSSQLServer, _connString, sql, null);
```

it comes back null but i can set and read it no problem in the management studio

```
EXEC sys.sp_set_session_context @key = N'TENANTID', @value = 'TEST_ID'
select SESSION_CONTEXT(N'TENANTID')
```

Any ideas why ?

Comment: How is `SPSDatabaseInfo` implemented ?

Comment: Can't really help without knowing how `sp_set_session_context` works or how the two commands are executed and when.

Comment: @CyrilDurand the execute scalars are wrappers to the Microsoft.ApplicationBlocks.Data.SqlHelper functions

Comment: @mxmissile - session_context is standard sql2016 and above functionality
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/session-context-transact-sql

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are using SPSDatabaseInfo.ExecuteScalar method sending a connection string instead of an open SQLConnection, that method internally is creating/opening/closing it's own connection.

That means that your calls are running under different sessions.

Use this overload of ExecuteScalar method using the same connection for both queries

```
public static object ExecuteScalar(SqlConnection connection, CommandType commandType, string commandText)
{
    //pass through the call providing null for the set of SqlParameters
    return ExecuteScalar(connection, commandType, commandText, (SqlParameter[])null);
}
```

this way

```
using (SqlConnection cn = new SqlConnection(_connString))
{
    cn.Open();
    String.Format("EXEC sp_set_session_context N'TENANTID', '{0}'", tenantId); 
    SPSDatabaseInfo.ExecuteScalar(cn, CommandType.Text, sql);

    sql = "select SESSION_CONTEXT(N'TENANTID') AS SESSION_ID"; 
    var retVal = SPSDatabaseInfo.ExecuteScalar(cn, CommandType.Text, sql);
}
```

Comment: Thanks @Daniel Brughera - indeed, that is the issue! :)